# Misplaced \noalign: I except to see \noalign only after the \cr of an alignment

Tags: tables, overleaf

This  my Table:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
    \fontsize{3}{5}\selectfont
    \tabcolsep=0.1cm
\caption{The type and number of refactorings performed on traditional OO code smells in the studied applications.} % title of Table
\label{NumberrefacOO}
\centering
 \resizebox{1.0\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{ll|llllllllll|c|c|}
\toprule
Refactoring & App & LC & CC & LPR & FE & LM & BC & MC & RB & SC & SG & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Total\\ Smelly\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Total\\ Non-Smelly\end{tabular} \\ \midrule
Extract Method &  \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  Apg & 2 & 50 & 37 & 72 & 106 & 12 & 20 & 1 & 29 & 8 & 337 & 523 \\
 & congress & 4 & 33 & 12 & 16 & 75 & 1 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 146 & 405 \\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}    Netguard& 2 & 13 & 0 & 100 & 87 & 3 & 28 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 241 & 622 \\
 & Notepad & 0 & 46 & 4 & 43 & 6 & 5 & 15 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 119 & 196 \\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  Omni-Notes & 2 & 3 & 0 & 2 & 24 & 3 & 36 & 0 & 50 & 0 & 120 & 554 \\ \midrule
Move Method & Apg & 0 & 38 & 9 & 46 & 28 & 6 & 6 & 0 & 11 & 0 & 144 & 183 \\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  congress & 7 & 5 & 15 & 14 & 4 & 1 & 12 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 58 & 255 \\
 & Netguard & 1 & 26 & 0 & 102 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 132 & 243 \\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  Notepad & 0 & 12 & 0 & 40 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 59 & 96 \\
 & Omni-Notes & 0 & 24 & 6 & 4 & 28 & 2 & 26 & 3 & 14 & 0 & 107 & 210\\ \midrule
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Extract and Move\end{tabular} & \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA} Apg & 0 & 13 & 4 & 11 & 13 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 53 & 180 \\
Method & congress & 2 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 11 & 155 \\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  Netguard & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 9 & 190 \\
 & Notepad & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 118 \\
&  \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA} Omni-Notes & 4 & 19 & 10 & 18 & 23 & 0 & 12 & 0 & 11 & 0 & 97 & 300 \\ \midrule
Inline Method & Apg & 0 & 4 & 0 & 4 & 4 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 21 & 95 \\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  congress & 0 & 0 & 6 & 12 & 13 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 37 & 87 \\
 & Netguard & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 82 \\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  Notepad & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 22 \\
 & Omni-Notes & 0 & 4 & 7 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 26 & 86 \\ \midrule
 Rename Method &\rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA} Apg & 1 & 39 & 33 & 37 & 76 & 4 & 15 & 0 & 13 & 7 & 225 & 354 \\
 & congress & 1 & 17 & 6 & 4 & 16 & 4 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 54 & 261 \\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  Netguard & 1 & 4 & 0 & 5 & 33 & 0 & 10 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 61 & 291 \\
 & Notepad & 0 & 20 & 10 & 20 & 24 & 1 & 20 & 1 & 16 & 0 & 112 & 252 \\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  Omni-Notes & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 11 & 0 & 12 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 25 & 267 \\ \midrule
Move Attribute & Apg & 0 & 10 & 7 & 6 & 8 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 42 & 170 \\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  congress & 0 & 4 & 0 & 36 & 10 & 2 & 16 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 68 & 476 \\
 & Netguard & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 5 & 93 \\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  Notepad & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 46 \\
 & Omni-Notes & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 13 \\ \midrule
Pull Up Method & \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA} Apg & 0 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 9 & 131 \\
 & congress & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  Netguard & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 & Notepad & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  Omni-Notes & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \midrule
Pull Up Attribute & Apg & 0 & 6 & 2 & 8 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 26 & 72 \\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  congress & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 & Netguard & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  Notepad & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 49 \\
 & Omni-Notes & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \midrule
Push Down Method &  \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}Apg & 0 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 17 & 20 \\
 & congress & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  Netguard & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 & Notepad & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  Omni-Notes & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \midrule
Rename Class & Apg & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  congress & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 5 \\
 & Netguard & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 7\\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  Notepad & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
 & Omni-Notes & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\ \midrule
Extract Super & \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA} Apg & 2 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 9 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 12 & 43 & 39 \\
Class & congress & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  Netguard & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 & Notepad & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  Omni-Notes & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 8 \\ \midrule
Move Class & Apg & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& \rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA}  congress & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
 & Netguard & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  &\rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA} Notepad & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 & Omni-notes & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \midrule 
\rowcolor[HTML]{DADADA} \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Total}} & \textbf{32} & \textbf{409} & \textbf{184} & \textbf{616} & \textbf{629} & \textbf{61} & \textbf{273} & \textbf{13} & \textbf{191} & \textbf{33} & \textbf{2,436} & \textbf{7,164} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

and this is the error:

```
\end{tabular}} 
 I except to see \noalign only after the \cr of an alignment
```

Comment: `&\rowcolor[`  you can only use `\rowcolor` at the start of the row. Did you intend `\cellcolor` (also unrelated but avoid using `\resizebox` on tables)

Comment: Please always post an example that can be run to produce the error that you ask about, in this case I happened to spot it by eye but it is much easier to test if you supply a an example document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle done

Comment: @AhmedAhmed See the first comment by David: `\rowcolor` has to appear **at the start of the row**, not at the end. Or use `\cellcolor` if you want to color only the last cell

Comment: Probably you're interested in columncolor since you seem to want to color the last cell in each row.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle   Ok thanks  this is done for this part but I have a question: If I want to color all the row excpet the first cell I'm using \rowcolor but I think it's causing also a problem so how can I replace it please

Comment: I edit other table with the same problem: thanks for your help in advance

Comment: use `\cellcolor in all but the first entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment I guess that you looking for something like this:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout. It is determined with `geometry` package).

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
    \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
    \linespread{0.8}\selectfont
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
\caption{The type and number of refactorings performed on traditional OO code smells in the studied applications.} % title of Table
\label{NumberrefacOO}
    \centering
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{white}
\begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{white}}p{4em}l
                              S[table-format=1.0]
                         *{2}{S[table-format=2.0]}
                              S[table-format=3.0]
                         *{6}{S[table-format=2.0]}
                              S[table-format=3.0]
                              S[table-format=3.0]  }
    \toprule
    \rowcolor{white}
    &      &     &      &       &      &      &      &      &      &      &     &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Total}   \\
    \cmidrule{13-14}
    \rowcolor{white}
Refactoring
    & App & {LC} & {CC} & {LPR} & {FE} & {LM} & {BC} & {MC} & {RB} & {SC} & {SG}
    & {\makecell{Smelly}} & {\makecell{Non-\\Smelly}} \\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
    &  Apg
        & 2 & 50 & 37 & 72 & 106 & 12 & 20 & 1 & 29 & 8 & 337 & 523 \\
\cellcolor{white}
    & congress
        & 4 & 33 & 12 & 16 & 75 & 1 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 146 & 405 \\
    & Netguard
        & 2 & 13 & 0 & 100 & 87 & 3 & 28 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 241 & 622 \\
\cellcolor{white}
    & Notepad & 0 & 46 & 4 & 43 & 6 & 5 & 15 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 119 & 196 \\
\multirow[t]{-5}{=}{Extract Method}
    & Omni-Notes
        & 2 & 3 & 0 & 2 & 24 & 3 & 36 & 0 & 50 & 0 & 120 & 554 \\ 
    \addlinespace
\cellcolor{white}
    & Apg
        & 0 & 38 & 9 & 46 & 28 & 6 & 6 & 0 & 11 & 0 & 144 & 183 \\
    & congress
        & 7 & 5 & 15 & 14 & 4 & 1 & 12 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 58 & 255 \\
\cellcolor{white}
    & Netguard
        & 1 & 26 & 0 & 102 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 132 & 243 \\
    & Notepad
        & 0 & 12 & 0 & 40 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 59 & 96 \\
\cellcolor{white}
\multirow[t]{-5}{=}{Move Method}
    & Omni-Notes
        & 0 & 24 & 6 & 4 & 28 & 2 & 26 & 3 & 14 & 0 & 107 & 210\\ 
    \addlinespace
    & Apg
        & 0 & 13 & 4 & 11 & 13 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 53 & 180 \\
\cellcolor{white}
    & congress & 2 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 11 & 155 \\
    & Netguard
        & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 9 & 190 \\
\cellcolor{white}
    & Notepad
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 118 \\
\multirow[t]{-5}{=}{Extract and Move}
    & Omni-Notes
        & 4 & 19 & 10 & 18 & 23 & 0 & 12 & 0 & 11 & 0 & 97 & 300 \\ 
    \addlinespace
\cellcolor{white}
    & Apg & 0 & 4 & 0 & 4 & 4 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 21 & 95 \\
    & congress
        & 0 & 0 & 6 & 12 & 13 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 37 & 87 \\
\cellcolor{white}
    & Netguard
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 82 \\
    & Notepad
        & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 22 \\
\cellcolor{white}
\multirow[t]{-5}{=}{Inline Method}
    & Omni-Notes
        & 0 & 4 & 7 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 26 & 86 \\ 
    \addlinespace
    &Apg
        & 1 & 39 & 33 & 37 & 76 & 4 & 15 & 0 & 13 & 7 & 225 & 354 \\
\cellcolor{white}
    & congress
        & 1 & 17 & 6 & 4 & 16 & 4 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 54 & 261 \\
    & Netguard
        & 1 & 4 & 0 & 5 & 33 & 0 & 10 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 61 & 291 \\
\cellcolor{white}
    & Notepad
        & 0 & 20 & 10 & 20 & 24 & 1 & 20 & 1 & 16 & 0 & 112 & 252 \\
\multirow[t]{-5}{=}{Rename Method}
    & Omni-Notes
        & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 11 & 0 & 12 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 25 & 267 \\ 
    \addlinespace
\cellcolor{white}
    & Apg
        & 0 & 10 & 7 & 6 & 8 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 42 & 170 \\
    & congress
        & 0 & 4 & 0 & 36 & 10 & 2 & 16 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 68 & 476 \\
\cellcolor{white}
    & Netguard
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 5 & 93 \\
    & Notepad
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 46 \\
\cellcolor{white}
\multirow[t]{-5}{=}{Move Attribute}
    & Omni-Notes
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 13 \\ 
    \addlinespace
    & Apg
        & 0 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 9 & 131 \\
\cellcolor{white}
    & congress
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    & Netguard
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\cellcolor{white}
    & Notepad
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\multirow[t]{-5}{=}{Pull Up Method}    
    & Omni-Notes
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    \addlinespace
\cellcolor{white}
    & Apg
        & 0 & 6 & 2 & 8 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 26 & 72 \\
    & congress
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\cellcolor{white}
    & Netguard
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    & Notepad
        & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 49 \\
\cellcolor{white}
\multirow[t]{-5}{=}{Pull Up Attribute}
    & Omni-Notes
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    \addlinespace
    & Apg
        & 0 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 17 & 20 \\
\cellcolor{white}
    & congress
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    & Netguard
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\cellcolor{white}
    & Notepad
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\multirow[t]{-5}{=}{Push Down Method}
    & Omni-Notes
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    \addlinespace
\cellcolor{white}
    & Apg
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    & congress
        & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 5 \\
\cellcolor{white}
    & Netguard
        & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 7\\
    & Notepad
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
\multirow[t]{-5}{=}{Rename Class}
\cellcolor{white}
    & Omni-Notes
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\ 
    \addlinespace
    & Apg
        & 2 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 9 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 12 & 43 & 39 \\
\cellcolor{white}
    & congress
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    & Netguard
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\cellcolor{white}
    & Notepad
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\multirow[t]{-5}{=}{Extract Super}
    & Omni-Notes
        & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 8 \\ 
    \addlinespace
\cellcolor{white}
    & Apg
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    & congress
        & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
\cellcolor{white}
    & Netguard
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    & Notepad
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\cellcolor{white}
    & Omni-notes
        & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Total}}
    & \textbf{32}    & \textbf{409}   & \textbf{184} & \textbf{616} & \textbf{629}
    & \textbf{61}    & \textbf{273}   & \textbf{13}  & \textbf{191} & \textbf{33}
    & \textbf{2,436} & \textbf{7,164} \\
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```